# Dynamically display images in layout

Tags: android

I have a Linear layout which contains 10 images (for example of beer mugs) 5 in upper row and 5 in second row but i want to display these images dynamically like if we get 3 value from server then two beer mugs will be displayed in upper row that too in the center and third mug will be displayed in second row that too in center.
Similarly if we get 7 value from server then 4 mugs will be displayed in upper row and 3 in second row.

Comment: Use GridView with  android:numColumns="auto_fit"

Comment: same thing i am implementing....

Comment: So what sort of help you want from us?

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal can u just explain me how r u implementing this.

Comment: i have also images comes from server and display with imageview in row wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context = null;

    private Button btnUpdate = null;

    private LinearLayout firstRow = null;
    private LinearLayout secondRow = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.context = this;

        this.firstRow = (LinearLayout) this
                .findViewById(R.id.ac_main__firstrow);
        this.secondRow = (LinearLayout) this
                .findViewById(R.id.ac_main__secondrow);

        this.btnUpdate = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ac_main__updatebtn);
        this.btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(onClickUpdateRow);


    }

    // I used this mothods only because i don't have a server that give me the value
    private int generateRandomInt() {
        Random rdm = new Random();
        return rdm.nextInt(9);
    }

    // Generate a new ImageView
    private ImageView generateImageView() {
        ImageView beerIcon = new ImageView(this.context);
        //Custumize this with your drawable
        beerIcon.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        return beerIcon;
    }

    private void updateImageRow() {
        int rdmValue = this.generateRandomInt();

        int rowOneImageNumber = rdmValue / 2;

        int rowTwoImageNumber = rdmValue - rowOneImageNumber;

        this.firstRow.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        this.secondRow.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        if (rowOneImageNumber >= rowTwoImageNumber) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= rowOneImageNumber; i++) {
                this.firstRow.addView(this.generateImageView());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= rowTwoImageNumber; i++) {
                this.secondRow.addView(this.generateImageView());
            }

        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i <= rowTwoImageNumber; i++) {

                this.firstRow.addView(this.generateImageView());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= rowOneImageNumber; i++) {
                this.secondRow.addView(this.generateImageView());
            }
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener onClickUpdateRow = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateImageRow();
        }

    };
```

And the `actvity_main.xml` is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ac_main__firstrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/ac_main__secondrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ac_main__updatebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update" />

    <!-- other layout element -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this put you in the right direction.

Comment: images are getting added vertically i.e one above the other not side by side @Roberto Lombardini

Comment: hey its working great...i was doing some mistake earlier.. thank you much... @Roberto Lombardini